# model can't see in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone i follow this toturial, [link text](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot)
and i write model.config and model.sdf under floder ~/.gazebo/models/my_robot$ dir. just like the toturials say ,but when i run the gazebo and select My robot , i can't see anything . does i forgot some thing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199707/model-can%27t-see-in-gazebo/) by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-12-18**:
If you aren't using ROS, there's [a forum for Gazebo specific questions](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using gazebo integrated with ros then this tutorial must be very much helpful.
[Mobile robot gazebo simulation](http://www.generationrobots.com/en/content/75-gazebo-and-ros).
It explains things with a mobile robot example.
OR follow the tutorial in gazebo website [Arm manipulator gazebo simulation](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control)

---

Originally posted by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) with karma: 233 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2014-12-30**:
@SVS thank you very much , by the way , i see the first web site , it seem like a robot introduce page , i can't find tutorial in this web site ;